# How is replacing $D^2$ with $-a^2$ justified when finding the particular integral?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I read in my engineering mathematics textbook that if we have a differential equation of the form $f(D)y=\cos(ax)$ or $f(D)y = \sin(ax)$ where $f(D)$ is a polynomial in $D$ i.e. $\frac{d}{dx}$ then we can find its particular integral using the following rule:

- Write P.I as  $$\frac{1}{f(D)} \cos(ax)$$ or $$\frac{1}{f(D)} \sin(ax)$$
- Replace all occurrences of $D^2$ in $f(D)$ with $-a^2$. For example if $f(D)$ is $2D^3+D^2+D$ then write it as $2D(-a^2)-a^2+D$.
- Then use the general methods to find evaluate the particular integral as usual.

But I'm not sure how the step in which we replace $D^2$ by $-a^2$ justified mathematically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because ultimately, $D^2$ is getting applied to $\sin(ax)$ and $\cos(ax)$, meaning that applying $D^2$ is the same as multiplying with $-a^2$.

Comment: In case the P.I is $\frac{1}{D^2}\sin(ax)$ I do not see how that is equivalent to multiplying $\sin(ax)$ by $-a^2$. $\frac{1}{D^2}$ is NOT the second derivative operator. This answer looks too short to be useful.

Comment: @alphauser When solving differential equations, _especially_ when trying to find a particular integral, it isn't worth it to be too obsessed about rigor, and whether things are truly correct. As long as the methods give you a correct answer in the end (which is easy enough to check, once you have one), it works. Personally, I would just have set $y=A\sin(ax)+B\cos(ax)$, applied $f(D)$ to $y$ and solved the two equations I got for $A$ and $B$. In that case, my answer is entirely correct.

Comment: I really don't care about solving the differential equation. I'm interested in understanding how the method arises in first place. From your answer and latest comment it is still not clear. If you mean that it somehow arises from assuming the solution to be $y=A\sin(ax)+B\cos(ax)$ then please elaborate on your answer.

Comment: To be honest, to me, $\frac1{f(D)}g(x)$ means "A function such that if you apply $f(D)$ to it, you get $g(x)$", which would mean that rewriting the original equation to $y=\frac1{f(D)}\sin(ax)$ is a step backwards, unless you have some theory on how to treat $\frac1{f(D)}$ (I assume the true answer your looking for is in that theory, using that we know that \frac1{f(D)}$ is applied to a sine wave). I have no idea why they do it. If you want information on the particular approach outlined in your question, then I can't help you.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, what you are using is the identity
\begin{align}
f(D)(e^{\lambda x}) = f(\lambda)e^{\lambda x}.
\end{align}
For instance,
\begin{align}
\left(\left( \frac{d}{dx}\right)^2-2\frac{d}{dx} -3\right)e^{\lambda x} = (\lambda^2-2\lambda-3)e^{\lambda x}.
\end{align}
Any how, if $f(\lambda) \neq 0$ then we have
\begin{align}
f(D)\left( \frac{e^{\lambda x}}{f(\lambda)}\right) = e^{\lambda x} \  \ \ \Longleftrightarrow \ \ \ f(D)^{-1}e^{\lambda x}=\frac{e^{\lambda x}}{f(\lambda)}
\end{align}
which means $f(\lambda)^{-1}e^{\lambda x}$ is a particular solution to the differential equation with forcing term $e^{\lambda x}$. Moreover, if $\lambda = ia$ then we have
\begin{align}
f(D)\left(\frac{e^{iax}}{f(ia)} \right) = e^{iax}. 
\end{align}
Since $f(D) = 2D^3+D^2+D$ then we have
\begin{align}
f(D)\left(\frac{e^{iax}}{-a^2-ia}\right) = e^{iax} \ \implies \ \ f(D)\left(\operatorname{Re}\left(\frac{e^{iax}}{-a^2-ia} \right) \right)=\cos ax.
\end{align}
Hence we see that
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Re}\left(\frac{e^{iax}}{-a^2-ia}\right)=\operatorname{Re}\left(\frac{-e^{iax}(a^2-ia)}{a^4+a^2}\right) = -\frac{a^2\cos ax+a\sin ax}{a^4+a^2}
\end{align}
is a particular solution.

**Edit:** Another way to make rigorous the solution to 
\begin{align}
P(D) y = f(x) 
\end{align}
is given by
\begin{align}
y = \frac{f(x)}{P(D)}
\end{align}
is by using Laplace transform. Since I only want a particular solution, I will impose an artifical initial condition $y(0) = y'(0) = \ldots = y^{(n-2)}(0) =y^{(n-1)}(0)=0$ if $P$ is degree $n$. Any how, by Laplace transform, we see that
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}(P(D)y)= P(s)Y(s) = F(s)
\end{align}
where $Y(s)$ is the Laplace transform of $y(x)$ and $F(s)$ the Laplace tranform of $f(x)$. In particular, you get that
\begin{align}
Y(s) = \frac{F(s)}{P(s)} \ \ \implies \ \ \ y(t) = \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left( \frac{F(s)}{P(s)}\right)
\end{align}

Comment: +1 I agree with the first part of your answer...I didnt get it with the Laplace transform though...